# SQL Server : values from two or more tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here is the situation: in my SQL Server 2008 database, there are some tables:

Table1

```
UID UserName HostName ServerID
-------------------------------
1    Sudheer  PC1       01
2    SAM      PC2       03
```

Table 2

```
ServerID   ServerName
----------------------
1           SRV1-DB1
2           SRV2-WEB
3           SRV3-Mail
```

I need output of `SELECT`:

```
UserName HostName  ServerName
-----------------------------    
Sudheer  PC1        SRV1-DB1
SAM      PC2        SRV3-Mail
```

Comment: I would recommend you look up how to join tables.  Then try it out, and if it doesn't work, post what you tried here, in your question, and we may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INNER JOIN`. Refer [this](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/W1aI140312-Different-Types-of-SQL-Joins.html) to learn JOINS in SQL SERVER

```
SELECT 
    A.UserName, A.HostName, B.ServerName 
FROM 
    Table1 AS A 
INNER JOIN 
    Table2 AS B ON A.ServerID   = B.ServerID
```